# Data notations are not rendered in publish mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, publish, entities

I have some Data Notations that works fine when I'm running my project through Visual Studio, but when I run this same project as a published project on IIS, using the same settings when I was runing by Visual Studio, the data notations are ignored. Look:

```
// my entity
[StringLength(1)]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MyResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CampoObrigatorio")]
public string MYPARAM { get; set; }
```

```
// my View
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MYPARAM )
```

```
// rendered DOM running by Visual Studio =]
<input data-val="true" data-val-length="just 1" data-val-length-max="1" data-val-required="Este campo é obrigatório." id="MYPARAM " name="MYPARAM " type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
```

```
// rendered DOM running by a published area =[
<input id="MYPARAM" name="MYPARAM" type="text" value="">
```

Someone have any clue about why does my published project do not render all those "data-stuff" as my local project?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `ClientValidationEnabled` is set to `false` in your published environment. This can be set in the Web.config for the entire project, and the default is `true`.

Add the following `AppSettings` keys, or find and modify them from `false` to `true`:

```xml
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Or you can set it individually in a specific view.

```cs
@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
}
```

This will add the `data-val-` attributes to your input fields; make sure you have the jQuery-validation script also added to the appropriate views, or the data annotations still won't be enforced.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help @user3347220! If you could, mark the answer as accepted; it could help others in a similar situation.